# Jquery : $(document).on('change', '.shipping_country', function() not working properly with dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery

In my form user has the option of adding multiple shipping addresses . I have some dynamically created sets of `countries dropdowns` with each having `class="shipping_country"` and `id="country_<?php echo $i;?>;`  and `states dropdowns` with each having `class="shipping_state"` and `id="state_<?php echo $i;?>;` .  The problem is that when user add multiple shipping address with same country in each address but different state then on every ajax call the state value selected in all the state dropdowns of shipping addresses becomes equal to the state value in the last state dropdown from the last shipping address. For example, If a user select `country=united states` in `first shipping address` and `state="Florida"`, in `second shipping address` `country=united states` and state=colorado then it will select state=colorado for both the shipping addresses. I think the possible solution is that if I can  use `attribute id` instead of class `$(document).on('change', '.shipping_country', function(){` but I don't know How to use dynamically created id here. ?

```
    *** check to load selected state and country ***
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['scountry'],$_SESSION['shipping_state']) && count($_SESSION['scountry']) && count($_SESSION['shipping_state'])>0){?>
var countryArray = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['scountry']); ?>;
var stateArray = '<?php echo implode(',',$_SESSION['shipping_state']); ?>';
<?php } ?>
    *** check to load selected state and country ***

 $(document).on('change', '.shipping_country', function(){
   var string_id=$(this).attr('id');
   var sid=string_id.split("_").pop();
   var id=$(this).val();
   var dataString = 'id='+ id;
       if(typeof stateArray !== 'undefined') {
          var str_array = stateArray.split(',');
       }
       $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "states.php",
         data: dataString,
         cache: false,
         success: function(html)
        {
           $("#state_"+sid).html(html);
            if(typeof str_array !== 'undefined'){
              for(var i = 1; i <= str_array.length; i++){
                 $("#state_"+sid+" option[value='"+str_array[i-1]+"']").attr("selected", "selected");
                            }
            }else{
                 $("#state_"+sid+" option:first-child").attr("selected", "selected");
            }
         }
      });
});
```

I have found that the loop in `ajax success` runs the number of times equal to the number of shipping addresses, I have added `console log` e.g. if I have 2 shipping addresses it gives me logs like this

```
2 State ID in if success #state_1
2 State ID in if success #state_2
```

This 2 is encircled indicating that this log comes twice, How Can I fix this???

```
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "states.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function(html)
       {
         $("#state_"+sid).html(html);
         if(typeof str_array !== 'undefined'){
           for(var i = 1; i <= str_array.length; i++){
               $("#state_"+sid+" option[value='"+str_array[i-1]+"']").attr("selected", "selected");
               console.log("State ID in if success #state_"+sid);  
           }
          }else{
           $("#state_"+sid+" option:first-child").attr("selected", "selected");
          }
       }
   });
```

**UPDATE:**

HTML Structure for states:

```
<span class="type1 form-group col-md-2"><span class="left-label"><span id="red">*</span>State/Province:</span>
    <select class="element select form-control shipping_state" id="state_<?php echo $i;?>" name="shipping_state[]">
        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['shipping_state']) && $_SESSION['shipping_state'][$i-1]!= ''){?>
        <option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['shipping_state'][$i-1]; ?>"><?php echo $_SESSION['shipping_state'][$i-1] ?></option>
        <?php }  else{ echo $us_statesList;  } ?>

    </select>
</span>
```

`HTML` is in a separate file `shipping.php` and `jquery` is in `header.php` I have tried doing like this

```
$(document).on('change', '#country_1,#country_2,#country_3', function(){
```

It did not work and if I do something like this that works then problem will be in that way I can not make sure if user only add 3 shipping addresses as they have option of adding as many as they want.

Comment: Because they have the same class try with unique ID. When the user adds any shipping address prepare dropdown using ajax and assign a unique id to every dropdown.

Comment: Use `table` ID as a unique `ID`

Comment: @Zaid Bin Khalid that is what my question is how can I use dynamically created id instead of class?

Comment: can you show your HTML structure?

Comment: added html structure for states

Comment: `$("#state_<?php echo $i;?>").on("change",function....` try with this. is this unique `$i` ?

Comment: this did not work as I have HTML is in a separate file shipping.php and jquery is in header.php

Comment: I have got it solved!